# NodeJS Express: How to interrupt the routing from outside the middleware/router?

Tags: node.js, express, terminate

I implemented a very simple middleware  to check the permissions for the user:

**app.js**

```
...
var security = require('./lib/security');
app.use(security.init);
...
```

**lib/security.js**

```
var session;
var request;
var response;

function init(req, res, next) {
  request = req;
  response = res;
  session = req.session;
  next();
}

function adminRequired(){
  if (!isAdmin()){
    response.redirect('/login');
    response.end();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
...
```

The best way I found to interrupt the flow is the following:

**routes/mycontroller.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(security.adminRequiredHtml()){return;} // now it actually interrupt the execution
  res.render('admin',{});
  res.end();
});
```

However, I would like to use it like this:

**routes/mycontroller.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  security.adminRequiredHtml(); // <- interrupt the request
  res.render('admin',{});
  res.end();
});
```

It correctly perform the redirect, but the execution continues :(
I've tried a few solutions like but it doesn't really work:
`response.end()` -> close the output but continues the execution
`process.end()` -> it's too radical, terminates the execution but it also kill the server :(

I've been thinking about using a `throw` but I don't know where to catch it and make it terminate gracefully (no stacktrace)

Comment: it's inelegant and may lead to confusion (and consequently to a security flow) due to the fact that the result on the browser it's correct but the execution continued.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom Router that is secured and add your secure Routes to that:

```
var secureRouter = express.Router();
// every request on this router goes throug this
secureRouter.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  if(isAdmin()) next();
  // if you don't call next() you interrupt the request automaticly
  res.end();
});

// protected routes
secureRouter.get('/user', function(req, res){/* whatever */});
secureRouter.post('/user', function(req, res){/* whatever */});

app.use(secureRouter);

// not protected
app.get('/api', function(req, res){/* whatever */});
```

[Express doc for using middlewares](http://expressjs.com/de/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: I would like to be able to use it directly in the controller method, the question is how to gracefully interrupt the routing.

Comment: Just dont call next() and the routing will end in your current handler.

Comment: Hem, I want to be able to use it like it was an "annotation", in this way I can easily protect single methods or just the "put" but not the "get" of the same url

Comment: okay I get what you want, but why not group all your protected routes under '/admin/..' for example?

Comment: becasue of admin it's easy, but for /api/ I want to be able to control "by method" so I can allow the GET but block the POST

Comment: mmm... really the question would be how to interrupt the routing gracefully outside the router/middleware (i edited the title)

Answer (score 1):

You're actually looking for middleware, I think.

```
function myMiddleware (req, req, next) {
   if (!isAdmin()) {
       res.redirect('/login');
       res.end();
   } else {
      //Proceed!
      next()
   }
}

router.get('/', myMiddleware, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('admin',{});
  res.end();
});
```

You can chain as many of those as you'd like to handle whatever logic you need. Just make sure you call `next()` if you're supposed to move on!